# Function overloading with generic types in Flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have a component

```js
<ButtonGroup
  value={value}
  options={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((x) => {
    return { label: x, value: x };
  })}
/>
```

I am using Flow for type checking and want to know, whether it is possible to have `ButtonGroup` component be generically typed in such a way that it will raise a Flow error if type of `value` is not the same as type of `option.[0].value`? This should work for any matching type, e.g number, array, etc. and only raise if type of `value` and `option[at_some_index].value` are different

What I currently have:

```js
type Props<T> = {
  options: Array<{
    label: React$Node,
    value: T,
  }>,
  value: T,

};
```

This works fine for checking matching types but only for a particular type. E.g if I do

```js
export const ButtonGroup = ({options, value}: Props<number>) => {do stuff}
```

It will work for number types as expected, but if I add union types to have the same behaviour for strings, arrays, like so `Props<number | string | []>` flow stops raising an error if types of values don't match.

Below also doesn't work:

```js
export const ButtonGroup = <T>({options, value}: Props<T>) => {do stuff}
```

I know [this can be done](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22415) in Typescript and was just wondering whether this can be done in Flow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that `T` gets replaced by `number | string | []` in all the instances. So you end up with

```
type Props<number | string | []> = {
  options: Array<{
    label: React$Node,
    value: (number | string | []),
  }>,
  value: (number | string | []),
};
```

Something like this might be more what you are looking for:

```
type NumOrStringStrictProps = Props<number> | Props<string>
```

Here is a flow [Try It](https://flow.org/try/#1N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALmAXwDTggEwKYogD0RABAAIwA2EA7gDpSMAuAngA56kAKAThOwDOAHgAqAPlIBeUsEalSA5nGiDkpAIK9eAQ1bC5UBQoBuOqgFc860Rnmk04u0dJnL10rcaM0Abm9QbJykAHIWALYARni8fAKC0jz8QsJQEdG84iwcXGHhAPK8AMrMvHBQCHFCiVUiaVExpAA+pIKl5QhZgTmhEYUlZRUDcGDMtTXJdekxki21wm2DnQGQUG2k9bXqeRnjMoYKSipr6gDawG5W6gCsaAC6zqbmV6TXPiuqzBvTvP3tFds+sV-pVJokDop2MpVGcLs8PLcHvZLh4AOQACTwOl4zFR7yYUBIpAAogAPTijEnaCC8Rirdb1DJ-JbDUbE6m8QEFYEs9qjPayexHGGkc4om73R6ueHqDFYnF4qBoD5rL6MmLMjqs5ghCDs-ic3rc4ZDPljMH7IVQ45qUVw9yy66oyXImWkOXY3E+EBYEwxQTHQgmAAMADoAIwATkjEZAaCAA) link to see an example